# Extract data from a json string with a structure language

Tags: php, json

I don't know if this thing exists or if a best practices already exists.

I have a json string and I would like to know if it's possible to extract data from this json using a query string like in sql.

Example with this json:

```
    [
  {
    "user": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Smith",
        "visits": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "date": "2016-08-30 16:00:00",
            "pageViews": 18
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Willis",
        "visits": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2016-08-30 18:00:00",
            "pageViews": 34
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I execute a query like `SELECT user.name WHERE user.visits.pageViews > 20` I get Willis

Else, what is the best way to do something like that in PHP ?

Thanks

Comment: Hmm, why not use `jq`? Also explain structure language?

Comment: array_filter() would be a good starting place

Answer (score 0):

Use `jq` which is the right tool for the job. Suppose `39233103.json` contains the sample input in the quesiton.

**Sample Run**

```
$ jq '.[]|.user[]|select(.visits[].pageViews>20)|.name' 39233103.json
"Willis"
```

To get the `raw output` use the `-r` option

```
$ jq -r '.[]|.user[]|select(.visits[].pageViews>20)|.name' 39233103.json
Willis
```

---

Now to do it from within php you could use [[ exec ]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). Suppose the below script is named `39233103.php`

```
<?php
$output=array();
exec("jq -r '.[]|.user[]|select(.visits[].pageViews>20)|.name' 39233103.json", $output);
foreach ($output as $val){
echo $val."\n";
}
?>
```

**Output**

```
$ php 39233103.php
Willis
```

---

If you're not familiar with `jq`, [[ this ]](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/jq-is-sed-for-json) is a good starting point.