# json, php - output string from array

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode JSON data to PHP then output it to the site. If I have the following:

```
{
  "name": "josh",
  "type": "human"
{
```

I can do this (within PHP), to display or output my `type`:

```
$file = "path";
$json = json_decode($file);

echo $json["type"]; //human
```

So, if I have the following:

```
{
  "name": "josh",
  "type": "human",
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "ben",
      "type": "robot"
    },
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "type": "alien"
    }
  ],
  "img": "img/path"
}
```

How can I output what `type` my friend `ben` is?

Comment: You are encouraged to use `jq` that is best suited for such jobs. You  might want to check my [\[ other answer \]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39233446/1620779) on a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop like foreach and do something like the following:

```
//specify the name of the friend like this:
$name = "ben";

$friends = $json["friends"];

//loop through the array of friends;
foreach($friends as $friend) {
    if ($friend["name"] == $name) echo $friend["type"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the decoded data in array format you would supply `true` as the second argument to `json_decode` otherwise it will use the default which is `object` notation. You could easily create a function to shorten the process when you need to find a specific user

```
$data='{
  "name": "josh",
  "type": "human",
  "friends": [
    {
      "name": "ben",
      "type": "robot"
    },
    {
      "name": "tom",
      "type": "alien"
    }
  ],
  "img": "img/path"
}';

$json=json_decode($data);
$friends=$json->friends;
foreach( $friends as $friend ){
    if( $friend->name=='ben' )echo $friend->type;
}

function finduser($obj,$name){
    foreach( $obj as $friend ){
        if( $friend->name==$name )return $friend->type;
    }
}

echo 'Tom is a '.finduser($friends,'tom');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$friend_name = "ben";
$json=json_decode($data);
$friends=$json->friends;
foreach( $friends as $val){
    if($friend_name == $val->name)
    {
        echo "name = ".$val->name;
        echo "type = ".$val->type;
    }    
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/4kINv)**